# Getting absolute file path from function handle

Tags: matlab, function-handle

Is there possibility to retrieve the absolute path to the file containing a function represented by a function handle? For example:

```
%child folder containing test_fun.m file
handle = @test_fun
cd ..

%root folder - test_fun not available
path = GETPATHFROMHANDLE(handle)
```

Is there equivalent to `GETPATHFROMHANDLE` function in MATLAB? It seems to by simple functionality, but I can't work it out. I know about `func2str` and `which` functions, but that doesn't work in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function handles (i.e. objects of [class `function_handle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html)) have a method called [`functions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html), which will return information about the handle, including the full path of the associated file:

```
>> fs = functions(h)
fs = 
    function: 'bar'
        type: 'simple'
        file: 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\bar.m'
>> fs.file
ans =
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\bar.m
```

Since the output of `functions` is a `struct`, this can be done in a single command with [`getfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html):

```
>> fName = getfield(functions(h),'file')
fName =
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\bar.m
```

However, you can use [`func2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/func2str.html) and [`which`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) to get the file name if you string them together:

```
>> h = @bar;
>> fName = which(func2str(h))
fName =
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\bar.m
```